# Magento 2 : Getting error - "Invalid state change requested" when placing order through my custom payment method

Tags: magento2, error, payment-methods

I am getting error - "**Invalid state change requested**" when placing order through my custom payment method on checkout page.

Comment: Did you find any solution or the reason for this problem?